# Permissions or ACL for Scheduled Tasks

Tags: task-scheduler, schtasks

I am on a Windows Server 2012 R2 and the logged in account is a member of Administrators.

This is a screen shot of Task Scheduler:

[image]

I have tasks in folders another administrator created: `RPA` and `Test`. Running `schtasks /query`, it lists only the `\` and `Microsoft` folders.

If I run `schtasks` in an elevated shell, I can see all the folders and tasks. What properties of a task make it visible or not visible to a user?  The two tasks in the Test folder were created by me the logged-in user, ie I am shown as the Author.

I am not related to the Microsoft's tasks in anyway, yet those tasks are listed.

Where is permissions or access control for Scheduled Tasks managed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The API provides a documented mechanism](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/registeredtask-setsecuritydescriptor) to set and query the ACL for a task or a [task folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/taskfolder-setsecuritydescriptor), but this doesn't seem to be exposed by the GUI or command line user interfaces.

On older versions of Windows, it appears that [the permissions are stored in the file system](https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/576-allow-to-view-and-run-scheduled-tasks-without-admin-rights) so you can view and/or modify them by looking at the permissions on the files and folders in the `c:\windows\system32\Tasks` folder.

On Windows 10, [the permissions are stored in the registry](https://serverfault.com/a/957060/94065).  Unfortunately, that leaves you with no built-in tools for manipulating them.  A Google search failed to turn up any third-party tools either.  See also [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/881144/94065).

Comment: How is the initial value determined or set? I have problems on a new machine and it appears that there is more to it than just file permissions. Please see https://serverfault.com/q/957039/245450.