# Unable to see Scheduled Task even with access rights to SYSTEM32\Tasks

Tags: scheduled-task, task-scheduler, schtasks

I have a follow-up question to [this](https://serverfault.com/a/954350/245450).

I have a task folder `RPA` with two tasks as follows:

[image]

I created these two tasks myself using the Task Scheduler UI (as in above image). My trouble is I am now unable to see `SPSBatch` using SchTasks.exe:

[image]

I am user BEETHOVEN\kingk and have the same Full access rights to both tasks in the `\Windows\System32\Tasks\RPA` folder:

[image]

Besides file permissions on the files in the Tasks folder, what else is controlling access to tasks?

Comment: I've extended those answers with a solution and script: https://serverfault.com/a/1046122/471857

Answer (score 2):

The security descriptor is stored in the registry, similar to what is done for services.

Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\RPA
Value: SD

Probably also a value for each task.

Comment: Yes, there's a `SD` value each for a folder and task. Is there any UI to view and update this? How is the default determined or set?

Comment: There is no UI.

Answer (score 1):

@OldGeezer @GregAskew thanks to your link to SD I was able to translate the binary SD to readable property with following Powershell:

```
$PathToTask = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\Microsoft"
$SDBin =  ( (get-itemProperty $PathToTask).sd )

ConvertFrom-SddlString ([wmiclass]"Win32_SecurityDescriptorHelper").BinarySDToSDDL($SDBin).SDDL
```

With the above you should be able to read what are the current ACLs, and if you work your way through methods from Win32_SecurityDescriptorHelper , you should be able to create your own ACL and replace it, giving you access to the task. I haven't tested that though